# Problema con cuadro de herramientas WebForms Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, webforms

Desde hace unos días he estado trabajando con un proyecto de WebForms de Visual Studio 2012. Pero hoy que intenté volver a trabajar, no puedo arrastrar objetos del cuadro de herramientas. No se como arreglarlo, podrían ayudarme? Ya intenté restablecer el cuadro de herramientas y elegir los elementos manualmente y nada. De ante mano Gracias

[image: ![Cuadro De Herramientas Vacío]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGFTr.png)

Comment: Una opción sería verificar si está en modo diseño *(form abierto y con focus)* si no. no le aparecerán los componentes para poder agregarlos.

Comment: Ya verifiqué eso @Dev.Joel y nada.

Comment: Pregunta obvia, pero reiniciaste el VS? Muchos de esos errores "raro" se corrigen con el principio número 1 de la informática: Reiniciar. Otra es cerrar el proyecto, reiniciar, cargar otro proyecto, y volver a cargar el proyecto con winforms...

Comment: Igual ya lo probé y nada Pablo. :/ Incluso si creo nuevos proyectos no me aparecen los componentes! Ya reinstalé visual. No se que mas hacer.